# How smart property works on basic bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, colored-coins, smartcontracts

How smart property works on basic bitcoin blockchain? I am not sure that how to make token, that is tied with a particular object, on the bitcoin blockchain. I've already know I can use such kind of token if I use colored coin or master coin.
I've read the following link, but I couldn't understand how it works.
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Smart_Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token in the blockchain *represents* a physical item, the same way that a paper document may represent a contract or ownership of a house.